# How to avoid login multiple times when having multiple connections to the same Teradata database in one Excel Sheet?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, database, odbc

I have an Excel 2010 document with several tables fetching data from different views in the same Teradata database using ODBC DSN connections. 
When I refresh the tables I am prompted to enter my login credentials once for each table, even though it is the same credentials for all of them.

I do not want to hard code my credentials into the sheet, but I would like to be able to login only once. Is this possible?

Edit: The workaround I ended up with was to store the password in the ODBC data source.

Comment: Post your macro using the { } keys for code blocking so we can see where you failed. You are most likely opening a new connection each time instead of opening a connection one time. Only need to close it at the very end of the code block and open once at the beginning.

Comment: Hi, I am not using any macro, just pressing the "refresh all" button. All connections are defined using standard Excel interface